# My .htaccess redirect is no longer working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess was working perfectly till yesterday. Surprisingly, I made no changes to the website.

The .htaccess lines redirects webite.com to https://www.website.com.
Right now, it redirects website.com to https://website.com

I tried modifying it but it did not change.

Find my .htaccess below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php?$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared hosting environment; another user may have introduced another .htaccess file which is over-riding your .htaccess file. How .htaccess files can override each other can be found here

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I am on a dedicated server and this is the root account.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current code to force `HTTPs` and `WWW` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Force SSL and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This will force `WWW` and `SSL` on everything.

Comment: Your code worked like a charm. It opened very well on my browsers but Pingdom sent me an email that my website is down. Other website showed my website as up except for Pingdom which we use for website monitoring. As soon as we switched back to previous lines, it became up on Pingdom. What is in the htaccess codes that makes the website unavailable for some services?

Comment: The only line at this moment I can see causing an issue is `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`. Which is why I recommended this alternative code. It's strange that some websites show your website as being up, and others as down. Would you be willing to provide your websites URL so I may run some tests of my own?